# Compound SQL INSERT statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql

How would I combine the following two statements to create a valid SQL query?

```
provider = os.path.basename(file)

cursor.execute("""INSERT into main_app_financialstatements 
                  (statement_id, provider_id***, url, date) 
                  VALUES (%s, %s***, %s, %s)""", 
                  (statement_id, provider***, url, date))

provider_id = SELECT id FROM main_app_provider WHERE provider=provider
```

In other words, I have the provider, and I need to SELECT the `provider_id` from another table in order to INSERT it into the `main_app_financialstatements`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT into main_app_financialstatements
  (statement_id, provider_id, url, date)
VALUES (%s, (SELECT id FROM main_app_provider WHERE provider=%s), %s, %s)""",
  (statement_id, provider, url, date))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM` variant of the [INSERT command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html):

```
provider = os.path.basename(file)

sql = """
    INSERT INTO main_app_financialstatements 
        (statement_id, provider_id, url, date)
    SELECT %s, id, %s, %s
    FROM main_app_provider
    WHERE provider = %s
    """ 
args = (statement_id, url, date, provider)
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```